# A combinatorics question

Tags: math, combinatorics

In how many different ways can a cube be painted by using three different colors of paint?

The answer of this is 45,

What if I change cube to cuboid?
Thanks!

I am preparing for job interview and this question is from CareeCup.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Ask on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should know how 45 is derived. That is by the use of permutation and combination.

Since a cuboid has the same number of sides as a cube, they should have the same answer. So the answer is 45.

But it is important to learn how the 45 is derived.

Comment: I am afraid this is not right...Hard to explain it.

Comment: Search into google about combination and permutation. Search also for examples. There are many example there which are similar to your problem.

Comment: This answer is right, and it is wrong not to accept or upvote it with a reason of "Hard to explain it".

Comment: answer for cuboid will differ since different sizes of faces.